# Run a powershell command from run.exe

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run this command that works perfectly fine, but from the run.exe

```
(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("host", "filename.ext");
```

Tried:

```
powershell.exe -noexit -Command "(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile(\"host\", \"filename.ext\");"
```

But I get this error:

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At line:1 char:1
+ (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("host ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

host and filename.ext are just placeholders.

Comment: By `run.exe` did you mean `cmd.exe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6) instead:

```
powershell.exe -c "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://server.domain.tld/path/to/file.ext -OutFile C:\path\to\save\download\file.ext"
```

If you need to use the old method, which is what you attempted above, you have escaped your quotes incorrectly. The download call should look like this:

```
powershell.exe -noexit -Command "(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile(`"host`", `"filename.ext`");"
```

Your problem with the command above is that you are trying to escape your double-quotes with a `\` instead of a `` ` ``. The escape character in PowerShell is `` ` ``. Of course, you could always avoid the need to escape your string by using a single quote for the `DownloadFile` parameter instead:

```
powershell.exe -noexit -Command "(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('host', 'filename.ext');"
```

---

Note that in PowerShell, double-quoted strings can have variables and subexpressions run directly in it, and can have escaped characters. Single-quoted strings escape all special characters and thus cannot have variables or subexpressions inserted directly into them. Both single-quoted and double-quoted strings do support [Format Strings](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.powershell-using-the-f-format-operator.aspx), however.

Comment: This definitely works but what will if the OP uses old powershell versions? Invoke-WebRequest is not available in all versions.

Comment: What do you mean by "late powershell versions"?

Comment: Good callout. I fixed the bug in OP's code and added it to my answer

Comment: How would I execute the same command but running the poweshell as administrator?
This is how I currently open powershell as administrator:
powershell Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs

Comment: Add `-Verb Runas` as an argument to powershell.exe

Comment: This, however, does not work: powershell Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -Command

No error is thrown.

Comment: Then you'd have to wrap your command inside a second powershell call to self elevate. A second option could be to use `runas /user:Administrator /savecred` so subsequent `runas /user:Administrator "program arguments"` calls don't prompt you for a password but this won't work in all environments.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Powershell.exe -NoExit -Command "& {$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient; $wc.DownloadFile(`"\\host\"`, `"targetfullpathname.ext"`)}"
```

A script block is needed to execute multiple commands.

Don't use backticks unless there are special miserable character(s).

Another method is already described by @Bender The Greatest.

Comment: A `ScriptBlock` is not needed to execute multiple commands. You just need to separate each statement with a `;`.

Comment: But isn't script block more flexible to execute multiple commands?

Comment: Not at all. A ScriptBlock is a set of multiple statements to be executed as a single unit. You would pass a scriptblock to `Invoke-Command` to run multiple statements, or you can also pass a string with multiple statements separated by semicolons. However, generally a ScriptBlock is easier to read, but if you're putting the code all on one line and separating the statements by `;` instead of newlines, then there's not really a reason to use one.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with singlequotes that cmd doesn't interpret like doublequotes.

```
powershell (new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://live.sysinternals.com/procmon.exe', 'procmon.exe')
```

Note that the first parameter is the full address of the file, not just the host.

```
powershell (new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
void DownloadFile(string address, string fileName)
void DownloadFile(uri address, string fileName)
```